# How to use Signalr in thread in Android java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, signalr

I want to use signalr in android java and I found signalr java sdk and I implemented them to my android project.

I can send message from android client to server via SignalR and I am getting this process under a background thread that I build with HandlerThread.

Here is the code snippet:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("ServerResponseHandlerThread",Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
handlerThread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

handler.post(Program::PingPong);
```

PingPong function:

```
while (true) {
    ConnectionState connectionState = HubConnection.getState();

    if(connectionState == ConnectionState.Connected) {
    }
    else if(connectionState == ConnectionState.Reconnecting || connectionState == ConnectionState.Connecting) {
        try {
            HubConnection.stop();
        } catch(Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
    else if(connectionState == ConnectionState.Disconnected) {
        try {
            Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

            HubConnection = new HubConnection(Global.ServerIP);
            HubProxy = HubConnection.createHubProxy("SignalRHub");

            HubProxy.subscribe(this);

            ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(HubConnection.getLogger());
            SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = HubConnection.start(clientTransport);

        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    HubProxy.on("response", (method, json) -> {
        switch (method) {
            case "PingPong":
                signalR.ResponseHandler.PingPong();
                break;
            }

            }, String.class, String.class);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

When I tried to get server response in a background thread it is not possible to get data from server. If I use this code on UI thread, it is working but I I use like that infinite loop locks UI thread and I don't want to lock UI thread.

Is there any possible way to use signalr with infinite loop in background thread? Besides, I want to get server response in this thread without locking UI thread.

Plus to this situation, I want to change UI component with background thread result.

How can I do all these?

Answer (score 0):

This seems (well, is) a bit over-engineered, considering how SignalR works under the hood. Have you looked at how the [library](http://github.com/SignalR/java-client/tree/master/signalr-client-sdk) is structured, and what threads it spawns on it's own? It makes large usages of Futures and Threads already. So, what's your motivation for creating it on another Thread?  Also, the `Thread.sleep(1000)` is one of the hints I'll give as to why it's probably not working as expected, but works on the main thread.

Secondly, take note of [this](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/blob/master/signalr-client-sdk-android/src/main/java/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/http/android/AndroidHttpConnection.java) class...it'll show a large amount of the work is already spawned in an `AsyncTask`.

Also under the same repo, there is a [link](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/tree/master/signalr-client-test-integration-android/src/main/java/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/test/integration/android) to android integration example usage, which may be helpful.

Comment: Client will always control connection between server in this thread forever. So it is continues process. I don't know how to handle it.I am very confused and I want to success that. Because I don't want to change communication technology to socket.io or websocket or another communication strategy.